# How can I remove Axis Lines from Vega Lite Chart

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

I'd like to remove / hide the axis lines from the vega-lite chart below.  I've tried changing the colour to null (as below) or other colours and that doesn't work.

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/fc799bc9f7a8f28b8f1f2ec84673e965/VL with axis lines.json

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"responseType": "Yes", "proportion": 28},
      {"responseType": "No", "proportion": 7}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "responseType",
      "type": "nominal",
      "title": null,
      "axis": {"axisColor": null, "grid": false, "ticks": false}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "proportion",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "% of Responses",
      "axis": {"axisWidth": "100", "grid": false, "ticks": false}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`domain` hides the axis lines, so setting `"axis": {"domain": false, "grid": false, "ticks": false}` for both x and y produces this chart:

[image]

If you also add `"config": {"view": {"stroke": null}}` as a top level property, you get rid of the grey outline:

[image]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tAZwBcAnCAa0xSgFcAbWgXwYBoQASfMAC0wFsBDFCC6FCAB3zIA9FLSYE-AHQI4hLtQBGiuBCmceA2fP4BaWqsyyArIoBW+aCFYATTJ2JwxhHVCEBBAAJ8OF4xWkwAjX5iAO5owgDsVS4Avg1MZ1dnAOd+QiUnEFz8vBA0flpqNxQAbVBiNzFofEwAFQBPMUpkEABNatYxUibib0dkACYADhZ6xua2zu6QADkIQqGIEbHfZAB2BgBdFhABYjIhKOJCzChIZzgoJFQQdtL4TFpnIQb8JqgWh0uoVCEshFAILxHhUQapwlQ6LRWPwAB5wfClZyQ-iPFAwCotVgIDzfZD42iEkDeMBkDFkgmYJisFHvLBfISbbY+EFgnoAR2o-Cg3ny3jksMI8J6AFIAhAYAEAErzAEDECo9GY7G4+kUzBEkl4hmsam0o16phMIA)