# Pivot transform in vegalite

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following dataset:

```
"data": {
"values": [{
        "service": "service1",
        "build": 5555,
        "branch": "develop",
        "env": "prod"

    }, {
        "service": "service2",
        "build": 5555,
        "branch": "develop",
        "env": "staging"

    }, {
        "service": "service3",
        "build": 5555,
        "branch": "develop",
        "env": "dev"

    }, {
        "service": "service4",
        "build": 5555,
        "branch": "develop",
        "env": "test"

    }
]
```

},

I want to show the data in the following way:

| service | dev | test | staging | production |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| service1 | 5555 | 5555 | 5555 | 5555 |
| service2 | 5555 | 5555 | 5555 | 5555 |
| service3 | 5555 | 5555 | 5555 | 5555 |

This is my example of what I did:
[enter link description here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABE2yGrIAEAIXVwkAazYNMFq7fuZFIAO41l9NCChymEgmcOruOpiCcGigmHAAHm6oANog5gw0gsqmsgwITKGmTACephChxDRQcDlICNEAukpIwmR6-nCycWFKysVo-ACMAAxKAGaBAOpwNGRYfkxsWe4Bgmxh6ADEACxjYgCcAOwo44EAyjQAXtGogwDMp11+ALKB5erqSJgKEEiyEPx3jQxiAAL5KAKyMazGIgJDxGgQWFkTTKNCYdQMOBKHRQGzmP5o9AJOJPUHglRfFCoUDEFpYpEpUDvSrVPxQCCyKIIzkJRFIHA0dxMDLLVBiCViJRMT6yWB+VSkNY4dydYh+HDqNho8HMipVG7+TncxGyPm-QXC0VEyVSkAyv7y9CKuDK1WydXoTXasEKPXqVmGjlc81mnkCoXS61oW3S2VOlRwJVsFVKNV+CBBWiyMi+-2B9nG0PmiNWzI2yVxx0wBVJ10p92exPq3UgFkGwshnlh-mWqPlmOV+3xmvOututMevxxTNghoUjF-CATdQINDJUCC4hsJIgTDFHDRJR0wRY9n2J5KFH2HAldcgdP95bzpogZDqGzTknugLKEy5mkQHiWFoVdIkHynHED0NdY-1kFp3BkdRd1UaBOjg3Nmh5WEIiiNBckEQQlEEJACkEABBHM8NQUYQBIsiADEphmOZd0WZZiNI10AGElnWPwdj2I4TjorjBCYroLmuNAACZaPo10AAUkGUDDZNo9YaE6XdMAbcklH6QDQLFe1oygw8-FgkwEKUJCklAYzwPbNklFg0JazQ2Q1NclV0AgPJfThbDANwm4CKI0SyMoshqPksSJMwaZZnmdB2LRTiyN4tYNhAQSDmOdwFPE84rhuEYMqUlS1PFckKRI4p3KZN8kA-PwrCgNwlC8HxRxGYZaM6X9-xAzJBFhKIyHQ-CGEI8YtJMkUB3Mw0AEcGD+CIvhoUhEKgFoblAWVJvvTY4CgMZ9jGEElE2KAADY4Cu67cuOZRLuenYZL2q6QHnWq-Wa1qQugr9EncCZJNKtAAA5Hl3V4uneT5vl+f5AVCYF3BaWZ2mqLp3IpQbtWGkLvyM+anP1NlavnIA)

How I can achieve that using vegalite?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061249/vega-table-using-text-marks

Comment: I already saw this. I need more concrete example, How I'm using the "env" variable to show the different environments as separate headers.

Comment: You mean you want to transform the data rather than display it that way?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question and added the json I'm tying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you get your desired output from your input but you can do this with a pivot transform:

[image]

```
 "transform": [{"pivot": "env", "value": "build", "groupby": ["service"]}],
```

Comment: You can share your entire json?

Comment: I don't have any more to share but that transform takes your input table and turns it into that output.

Comment: Glad you sorted it!